# Validate JSON object against a flexible set of rules?

Tags: json, clojure, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am use `metosin/scjsv` to validate the json body of a POST request.

I would like to validate against the following rules:

- Any value should be allowed for the element key within the mapping object so long as it conforms to this regex: `^[a-z_][a-z\\d_]*$`
- Only the object: `{:attribute : {:type "string"}}` should be allowed as the value of an element within the mapping object.

This is an example of a valid json object:

```
{
   "mapping" : {
              "attr_a" : {
                          "attribute" : "a"
                         },
              "attr_b" : {
                          "attribute" : "b"
                         }
             }
 }
```

Here is the schema I have defined so far, it fails to valid how I would like it to:

```
(def schema {:type       "object"
         :properties {:mapping {:type    "object"
                                :pattern "^[a-z_][a-z\\d_]*$"
                                {:$attr {:type       "object"
                                         :properties {:attribute {:type "string"}}
                                         :required   [:attribute]}}}}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have used `patternProperties` and `additionalProperties`.

```
(def schema {:type       "object"
     :properties {:mapping {:type    "object"
                            :patternProperties {"^[a-z_][a-z\\d_]*$" {:type       "object"
                                     :properties {:attribute {:type "string"}}
                                     :required   [:attribute]}}}}})
```